# celebrate npm package con Nest Framework

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, backend

Existe alguna forma de usar el [paquete NPM celebrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/celebrate)  con el [Framework Nest](https://nestjs.com/)?
En la documentación solo se refieren a [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator), pero aunque este tiene muchas ventajas he usado con `Express` y otros frameworks el middleware celebrate para validar el request. En el caso de `Nest` la configuración del `middleware` se hace el `app.module.ts`, pero en otros como [routing-controllers](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers) se hace uso del decorador `@UseBefore` para los middlewares en las controllers, es por ello que agradeceria cualquier explicación, ejemplo o documentación de como usar este middleware con Nest. Gracias!!

Comment: por favor revisa [ask] esta pregunta es confusa y muy amplia, es decir ya leiste la documentación de ambas herramientas? que has tratado? ya probaste tratar de instalarlo? que fallos hubo?

Comment: es decir ese paquete para que sirve? ya verificaste si el framework no tiene alguna herramienta similar?

Comment: @shadow he editado la pregunta. Disculpenme por la ambiguedad del texto anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí esta la solución:

En un fichero dedicado a las validaciones crear el `middlware` con el esquema a usar por `celebrate` (este sería un simple ejemplo para una autenticación):

```
import { celebrate, Joi } from 'celebrate';

export const authenticate = celebrate({
    headers: Joi.object().keys({
        client: Joi.string().required(),
        application: Joi.string().required(),
    }).unknown(),
    body: Joi.object().keys({
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
});
```

¿Cómo usarlo luego? Lo importas en el módulo y lo aplicas como `middleware`, ya que celebrate devuelve una función de la forma `function(req, res, next)`:

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
// Otros imports ...
import { authenticate } from './validations/authenticate.validation';


@Module({
    imports: [ // Tus imports... ],
    controllers: [ // Tus controladoras... ],
    providers: [ // Tus providers... ],
})
export class AuthenticationModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        // Validate Login.
        consumer.apply(authenticate).forRoutes({ path: 'security/login', method: RequestMethod.POST });
    }
}
```

El `path` definido en la configuarción debe obviamente coincidir con el del `endpoint` de la controladora:

```
import {
    Body,
    Post,
    Headers,
    Controller,
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('security')
export class AuthenticationController {

    @Post('login')
    async authenticate(
        @Body('email') email: string,
        @Body('password') password: string,
        @Headers('application') application: string): Promise<any> {

        // Autenticar usuario
    }
}
```

Se puede ver también:

https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

https://www.npmjs.com/package/celebrate

Comment: excelente ejemplo, gracias por compartirlo, me servirá ahorita que voy a empezar a trabajar con este framework